# Need help for show name players online (PHP)

Tags: php

I need help to show the name of players online on my website.

I have already all and all work but when I choice rank 0 (members) you see 1000 players online / offline.

I want it shows only players (online) and hide players (offline) I hope you know what I mean

My code:

```
<?php               
    $findAdmins = $odb->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `rank` = '1'");

    while($rowAdmins = $findAdmins->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {    
        $diffOnline = time() - $rowAdmins['activity'];

        $countOnline = $odb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username  AND {$diffOnline} < 60");

        $countOnline->execute(array(':username' => $rowAdmins['username']));

        $onlineCount = $countOnline->fetchColumn(0);

        $logo = "fa fa-ban";

        if($onlineCount == "1") {  
            echo '<li><a href="#"><i></i><center>'. $rowAdmins['username'] .'  <span class="labelon " style="border-radius:3px; color:white; float:right; font-weight:500; padding:6px; background-color:#1388a0;">Online</span></center></a></li>';
        } else {     
            echo '<li><a href="#"><i></i><center>'. $rowAdmins['username'] .'  <span class="labelon " style="border-radius:3px; color:white; float:right; font-weight:500; padding:6px; background-color:#f71c11;">Offline</span></center></a></li>';
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've made this very over-complicated - what you want can be done in a single query much more efficiently. And if, as you stated, you only want it to show players who are online then you don't need the piece of code which echoes the "Offline" text. If that's your requirement then I'm not sure why you added that line :-)

This query will return all "online" users with the requested rank:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `rank` = 0 and unix_timestamp() - `activity` < 60
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5fc7238d7c9ecc968fef7da4e4657a9d

So the PHP code can be simplified to just:

```
$findAdmins = $odb->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `rank` = 0 and unix_timestamp() - `activity` < 60");

while($rowAdmins = $findAdmins->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
  echo '<li><a href="#"><i></i><center>'. $rowAdmins['username'] .'  <span class="labelon" style="border-radius:3px; color:white; float:right; font-weight:500; padding:6px; background-color:#1388a0;">Online</span></center></a></li>'
}
```

This will return all the online users with that rank and echo a link for each one.

---

P.S. Just a side note, the `<center>` tag in HTML is [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) - you should use the CSS `text-align` property to centre your text instead. Consider changing this part of your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a second query? If you judge `$onlineCount == 1`, then the username field is unique, and the `$diffOnline` variable remains unchanged after calculation. The comparison with constant 60 is fixed. Try this code:

```
$findAdmins = $odb->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `rank` = '0'");

while($rowAdmins = $findAdmins->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
    $logo = "fa fa-ban";

    if(time() - $rowAdmins['activity'] < 60) {  
        echo '<li><a href="#"><i></i><center>'. $rowAdmins['username'] .'  <span class="labelon " style="border-radius:3px; color:white; float:right; font-weight:500; padding:6px; background-color:#1388a0;">Online</span></center></a></li>';
    } else {     
        echo '<li><a href="#"><i></i><center>'. $rowAdmins['username'] .'  <span class="labelon " style="border-radius:3px; color:white; float:right; font-weight:500; padding:6px; background-color:#f71c11;">Offline</span></center></a></li>';
    }
}
```